# is it possible to add extra data to a struct in boost

Tags: c++, boost

Hello so if i have class like this

```
class Doors
{
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <class Ar>
    void serialize(Ar &ar, unsigned)
    {
        ar &username &password;
    }

public:
    string username;
    string password
};
```

and then i serialized the class and added it to MySql then later i decided to edit that struct and add some more data to it like this

```
class Doors
{
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <class Ar>
    void serialize(Ar &ar, unsigned)
    {
        ar &username &password &email &phone;
    }

public:
    string username;
    string password;
    string email;
    string phone;
};
```

now i already have some serialized data in MySql before editing the struct if i deserialize it it will show boost error because i have modified the struct now my question is

is it possible to take the old class then add the new data to it ?
because i dont want to delete the old ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice the second argument to `serialize()` which you're not using, it's the class version.

You can bump the class version and optionally read the additional fields depending on the version.

```
class Doors
{
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <class Ar>
    void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned version)
    {
        ar &username &password;
        if (version > 0) {
            ar &email &phone;
        }
    }

public:
    string username;
    string password;
    string email;
    string phone;
};

BOOST_CLASS_VERSION(Doors, 1);
```

The default version is 0. So your old format with no class version defined will have version 0.

Comment: Doin' the Lord's work :) Also thanks for helping out with the comments on the `receive_from` question. It's nice knowing I can be afk for a while!